# Binding date variables into a SQLite WHERE query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to select the vouchers from a db that have the voucherDate between two given dates, passing the dates into the query as variables.

This works:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE voucherDate BETWEEN date('2022-01-06') and date('2022-01-08')""")
```

and I think the final result is meant to look like this:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE voucherDate BETWEEN voucherDate=? and voucherDate=?""", (date1, date2))
```

Passing the date parameters as strings

```
date1 = 'date("2022-01-06")'
date2 = 'date("2022-01-08")'
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE voucherDate BETWEEN voucherDate=? and voucherDate=?""", (date1, date2))
```

doesn't work, and something like

```
date1 = "date('2022-01-06')"
```

doesn't workeither, nor does

```
date1 = date("2022-01-06")
```

compute.

so I don't know how to make this work. Can I break it up some other way?
Maybe I'm just missing an apostrophe?

Thanks so much for any help!

Edit: **SOLUTION**

```
date1 = "2022-01-06"
date2 = "2022-01-08"
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE voucherDate BETWEEN ? and ?""", (date1, date2))
```

Comment: the final result is meant to look like this: `SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE voucherDate BETWEEN ? and ?`.

Comment: Since `date("2022-01-06")` in SQLite just returns the string `2022-01-06`, set date1 to `"2022-01-06"`